# Pandas contains not matching full string

Tags: pandas, contains

I'm having trouble with this `.contains` function for this `df`. Why doesn't it match my string? Clearly the `df` has the string. It matches "Chief" alone.

```
import pandas as pd
link = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1448056/000119312518215760/d619223ddef14a.htm'
ceo = 'Chief Executive Officer'
df_list = pd.read_html(link)
df = df_list[62]
df = df.fillna('')

for column in df:
    if column == 4:
        print ('try #1', df[column].str.contains(ceo, case=True, regex=True))
        print ('try #2', df[column].str.contains(ceo, case=True, regex=False))
        print ('try #3', df[column].str.contains(ceo, regex=False))
        print ('try #4', df[column].str.contains(ceo, regex=True))
        print ('try #5', df[column].str.contains(pat=ceo, regex=False))
        print ('try #6', df[column].str.contains(pat=ceo, case=True, regex=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the encoding, you can see it if you do:

```
df[4].iloc[2]
```

because it prints:

```
'Founder,\xa0Chief\xa0Executive\xa0Officer,\xa0and\xa0Director'
```

And to fix it, use unidecode:

```
import unidecode

for column in df.columns:
    if column == 4:
        print ('try #1', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(ceo, case=True, regex=True))
        print ('try #2', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(ceo, case=True, regex=False))
        print ('try #3', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(ceo, regex=False))
        print ('try #4', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(ceo, regex=True))
        print ('try #5', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(pat=ceo, regex=False))
        print ('try #6', df[column].apply(lambda x: 
        unidecode.unidecode(x)).str.contains(pat=ceo, case=True, regex=True))
```